# Como criar uma "Coluna Virtual" no select usando KNEX JS?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Estou usando o Knex em meu projeto e preciso fazer uma consulta na tabela pessoas e nesta consulta acrescentar um "Campo Virtual" que não existe na tabela.
Isso no MySQL ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
  p.RAZAO_SOCIAL,
  'umValorQualquer' as ColunaVirtual 
FROM pessoas p;
```

E teria este Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu problema é criar o campo virtual. Como faço este select usando o Knex?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver usando o Raw dentro do Select.

```
knex('pessoas as p')
    .select(
        p.RAZAO_SOCIAL
        knex.raw("'umValorQualquer' as ColunaVirtual")
     )
```